# AnytingSlider expand and resizecontents together drops slide height to 2px

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

If I try to use AnytingSlider expand and resizecontents together it drops slide height down to 2px
Without *resizecontent true* slides are appearing correctly.
I have set height in CSS, and looked inside js but have no idea why this is happening

CSS

```
#slider1 {
    width: 700px;
    height: 280px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


body
....
<div class="box">
  <div id="banner-full">
    <div id="page-wrap">
       <div id="hover">
         //...some hover over slider...//
       </div>
       <div class="anythingSlider anythingSlider-metallic activeSlider" style="width: 617px; height: 2px;">
          <div class="anythingWindow" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <ul id="slider1" class="anythingBase horizontal" style="width: 3085px; left: -617px;">
              <li class="cloned panel" style="width: 617px; height: 2px;">
              <li class="panel activePage" style="width: 617px; height: 2px;">
              <li class="panel" style="width: 617px; height: 2px;">
              <li class="panel" style="width: 617px; height: 2px;">
              <li class="cloned panel" style="width: 617px; height: 2px;">
            </ul>
          </div>
        <div class="anythingControls" style="display: block;">
            //...some controls html...//
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `expand` option,

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    expand: true
});
```

you need to wrap the slider in an element that isn't the document body ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/4088/)):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="slider">
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/500/200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placebear.com/500/200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placedog.com/500/200" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now all that's left is to define the size of the `.wrapper`:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry, in my case slider is not directly in body. I just didnt write here _all_ the htlm code. Its just too mutch code but I improved this part of code in qestion